# How to run android simulator with flutter on android studio im mac M1?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have android studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4 installed on MacBook M1.
There I want to Pixel 6a API 33 as device. But when I choose it and press 'Run main.dart' the simulator is not opening. That happens with any 3 android devices that I run in the simulator. If I run 'flutter doctor' I do not get any errors.
Only if I run the device in the device manager the simulator os opening in a window. Is this now the default behaviour?
Or how to run and see the simulator opening an android device?

As AVD I have Tiramisu Android 13.0 arm64-v8a.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: try running the emulator first then running app,

Comment: It is the same.
Previously I have been using VS Code. There it is the simulator also not starting. I have updated Android Studio. Could it be because of that?

Comment: sometimes updating android studio causes update, i strongly recomment uninstalling android studio and deleting all files, then re-installing new version,